# How to set WebRTC data channel max bitrate?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, sdp, ice, rtcpeerconnection

I would like to set the max bitrate that my WebRTC client can support. I only have access to the client (receive video frames) not to the host (sending video). How do I go about signaling that my client can only support a low bitrate (512kbps for example).

So far I have tried to modify the SDP offer adding the `b=AS` field to try to set the max bitrate. Here is the code I have:

```
const rtcPeer = new RTCPeerConnection()
...
rtcPeer.createOffer().then((offer) => {
    offer.sdp += `b=AS:512\r\n`; // <-- trying to set max bitrate to 512 kbps here
    rtcPeer.setLocalDescription(offer)
    ...
}
```

The full SDP that this creates looks like this:

```
v=0
o=- 2186277925215273999 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:7+MK
a=ice-pwd:removed
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 05:37:61:F1:48:8B:0B:9D:77:84:2C:74:5E:E3:25:7B:86:D2:E2:CF:E1:5E:A2:F6:14:C2:F5:9C:03:38:3D:ED
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=sctp-port:5000
a=max-message-size:262144
b=AS:512
```

Note, my SDP offer doesn't have a `m:video` or `m:audio` because its just a data channel that frames are sent over (I have no control over this; the host). I am not sure if not having `m:video` will make it so I cant sent the max bitrate? More details on this here: https://webrtchacks.com/limit-webrtc-bandwidth-sdp/

My questions are:

1. Is setting `b=AS` in the SDP offer the correct way to set the max bitrate?
2. Will this work over a normal data channel (non `m:video` offer in the SDP offer)?
3. Is the bitrate enforced on the client side or the host side? Im wondering if its possible the that WebRTC host isn't setup to respect this parameter? And just continues to send video frames at whatever rate it wants?
4. I see other ways to set the bitrate, for example here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpEncodingParameters/maxBitrate. Are there other ways to set the bitrate?

For extra details, here are the bitrates I recorded with and without the `b=AS:512` flag. Its spiking up to 6mbps and in somecases > 10mbps I noticed (which is much too large).

[image]
[image]

Appreciate any help you guys can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to control data channel bandwidth, forget about recipes related to RTP bandwidth control because they are for audio and video only. There is no such "magic" option in a browser (at least for today), but you can implement data channel bandwidth control in your JavaScript application by yourself.

First, keep transmitted messages size lower than the lowest value of the `max-message-size` parameter. Even though some modern [browsers allow a message size of up to 1Gb](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/large-data-channel-messages/) (and more), my advice is not to exceed 128Kb. If the message size is larger than allowed, you can split it into chunks on the sender side and reassemble it on the receiver side.

Second, look after the buffer size of the data channel on the sender side [`RTCDataChannel.bufferedamount`](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/large-data-channel-messages/). It is easy to overflow the buffer at the low network bandwidth and intensive write to the data channel, so the data channel will go into the closed state.

Comment: Dang, ok so since I have no control over the sender (and thus cant adjust the `RTCDataChannel.bufferedamount`) it sounds like it's simply not possible for me to adjust the bitrate at all. Correct?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you want to limit the data channel bandwidth of an application you can control as a developer? Or do you want to limit the data channel bandwidth of a third party application as a peer? Maybe you want to limit the video bitrate you receive through the data channel?

Comment: I would like to limit the data channel bitrate my application receives. Keeping in mind I only control the receiver application as a developer. The sender application is from a 3rd party and I have no control over it (but it is webrtc compliant).

Comment: Got it. Then there is no straight way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `b=AS` will influence the SCTP congestion control. I am going to look deeper in libwebrtc, but it is a RTP specific value.

How much control do you have on the client? Is it just a browser? Is it mobile? Is it a process running on Linux/Windows?

With SCTP you have a `a_rwnd` which communicates how much buffer space you have as a receiver. You could artificially limit this to cause the sender congestion controller to get the behavior you want?

Comment: I have control of the client via browser only. The client is just running in a browser with js via `RTCPeerConnection()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection). I am not familiar with setting `a_rwnd`. Can you should me how to artificially limit this value in a browser? (and thanks for looking into this!!)